# jQuery Contains/Not Contains with Date Range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a list of items with attributes such as order number and date ordered. My goal is to load all of the user's orders into these item divs and allow them to filter. I have it correctly filtering when the user types the order number into a text field. Now I am trying to allow them to pick a Date From and Date To range and have the divs hide or display as necessary.

Here is a sample div:

```
<div class="item" data-orderNo="457748322" data-dateOrdered="12/17/2014">
    ... Order Details ...
</div>
```

I am able to filter them by order number with this code:

```
$('#orderNumberFilter').keyup(function () {
   var orderNo = $(this).val();
   if (orderNo == "") {
        $(".item").removeClass( "hiddenOrderNo" );
    } else {
        $(".item[data-orderNo*='"+orderNo+"']").removeClass( "hiddenOrderNo" );
        $(".item:not([data-orderNo*='"+orderNo+"'])").addClass( "hiddenOrderNo" );
    }
});
```

Finally, I have two datepicker fields: fromDateFilter (earliest date) and toDateFilter (latest date). I'm trying the following but it's not working:

```
$( "#fromDateFilter" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function ( selectedDate ) {
        if(selectedDate == "") {
            $(".item").removeClass( "hiddenDateFrom" );
        } else {
            var start = new Date(selectedDate);
            var end = new Date($(".item").attr("data-dateOrdered"))
            if (start < end) {
                $(".item:not([data-dateOrdered*='"+selectedDate+"'])").addClass( "hiddenDateFrom" );
            } else {
                $(".item[data-dateOrdered*='"+selectedDate+"']").removeClass( "hiddenDateFrom" );
            }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The toDateFilter is the same, I've just tried to switch the carrot direction. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need a single filter method like

```
function filter() {
    var orderNo = $('#orderNumberFilter').val(),
        fd = $("#fromDateFilter").datepicker('getDate'),
        td = $("#toDateFilter").datepicker('getDate'),
        $items = $(".item"),
        $filtered = $items;
    if (orderNo != "") {
        $filtered = $filtered.filter("[data-orderNo*='" + orderNo + "']");
    }else if(!fd && !td){
        $items.removeClass('hiddenOrderNo');
    }

    $filtered = $filtered.filter(function () {
        var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $(this).attr('data-dateOrdered'));
        return (fd == null || date >= fd) && (td == null || date <= td);
    });
    $filtered.removeClass('hiddenOrderNo');
    $items.not($filtered).addClass('hiddenOrderNo');
}
```

which is called on change of both the text field and date fields

```
$('#orderNumberFilter').on('keyup', filter);
$('#fromDateFilter, #toDateFilter').datepicker({
    onClose: filter
});
```

```js
//to display some content, for demo only
$('.item').html(function() {
  return $(this).attr('data-orderNo') + '-' + $(this).attr('data-dateOrdered')
})

function filter() {
  var orderNo = $('#orderNumberFilter').val(),
    fd = $("#fromDateFilter").datepicker('getDate'),
    td = $("#toDateFilter").datepicker('getDate'),
    $items = $(".item"),
    $filtered = $items;
  if (orderNo != "") {
    $filtered = $filtered.filter("[data-orderNo*='" + orderNo + "']");
  } else if (!fd && !td) {
    $items.removeClass('hiddenOrderNo');
  }

  $filtered = $filtered.filter(function() {
    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $(this).attr('data-dateOrdered'));
    return (fd == null || date >= fd) && (td == null || date <= td);
  });
  $filtered.removeClass('hiddenOrderNo');
  $items.not($filtered).addClass('hiddenOrderNo');
}

$('#orderNumberFilter').on('keyup', filter);
$('#fromDateFilter, #toDateFilter').datepicker({
  onClose: filter
});
```

```css
.hiddenOrderNo {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="orderNumberFilter" />
<input id="fromDateFilter" />
<input id="toDateFilter" />
<div>
  <div class="item" data-orderno="457748322" data-dateordered="12/17/2014">457748322-12/17/2014</div>
  <div class="item" data-orderno="854455225" data-dateordered="12/18/2014">854455225-12/18/2014</div>
  <div class="item" data-orderno="7155222" data-dateordered="12/19/2014">7155222-12/19/2014</div>
  <div class="item" data-orderno="984445622" data-dateordered="12/17/2014">984445622-12/17/2014</div>
  <div class="item" data-orderno="123584397" data-dateordered="01/15/2015">123584397-01/15/2015</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: One more question - how would I change this from looking for a data attribute and instead to look for content within the div? I am able to get an alert that comes up with the text I want to search using this:

$(this).find( "p.partListing" ).text()

Comment: Would it be something like this?

  if (partNo != "") {
   $filtered = $filtered.$(this).find( "p.partListing" ).filter(function () { return / + partNo + /.test(this.innerHTML); });
  } else if (!fd && !td) {
   $items.removeClass('hiddenOrderNo');
  }

Comment: what will be a sample content of `partListing`

Comment: `<p class="partListing"><a href="#" target="_blank">IMG23CJ+</a>, <a href="#" target="_blank">IMG####AC/D</a>, <a href="#" target="_blank">IMG232AC/D</a>, <a href="#" target="_blank">IMG230AC/D</a>, <a href="#" target="_blank">IMG###ACPE</a>, <a href="#" target="_blank">IMG###AC/D</a>, <a href="#" target="_blank">IMG###ACJ+</a></p>`

Where I only want to search on the text, e.g. IMG###AC/D

Comment: @Lauren there are lot of data within the div, do you want to look inside a particular element